# Best way to group #defines

Tags: c++, c

I have a bunch of `#define`, generated by Visual Studio, whose values I can not control. They are paired in groups of 3, e.g

```
CFG_FILT0
CFG_FILT1
CFG_FILT2
CFG_DELTA0
CFG_DELTA1
CFG_DELTA2
...
```

In the current class I am working with I would like to have a local (`private` and `const`) structure, which encapsulates all of these `#define`. Then, some functions of this class will need to read these values, **but only in the before mentioned groups of 3**. The potentiall structure (`myStruct`) should allow for something like this:

```
for (int idx = 0; chIdx < 3; idx++)
{
    GetItem(myStruct[idx].filt)
    GetItem(myStruct[idx].delta)
    ...
}
```

What is the best way to define such a structure, in terms of readability and memory usage?

Note that I would rather have just one structure, rather than one for each group of 3 `#define` (e.g. `myStructFilt`, `myStructDelta` in the above example)

Comment: "Note that I would rather have just one structure, rather than one for each group of 3"  So why don't you make a structure containing an array of 3 items?

Comment: Without a *much* more specific use-case, we can only guess to what the most useful goal is and how to get there.

Comment: Values of indices for all usages of potential `GetItem()` are known at compile time? I.e. it looks like `GetItem(1), GetItem(10)` or it will be variables?

Comment: @Serhio yes, they will be known at compile time

Comment: You can't "encapsulate" macros.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that this is what you really want, but you can get access interface similar to you described with next macro:

```
#define GET(kind, idx) ( \
        (idx) == 0 ? CFG_ ## kind ## 0 \
      : (idx) == 1 ? CFG_ ## kind ## 1 \
      : (idx) == 2 ? CFG_ ## kind ## 2 \
      :  -1 /* or you can assert() here*/ )
```

And usage looks like:

```
GET(FILT, 0);
GET(DELTA, 2);
```

Of course such approach has some drawbacks, at least it is multiple evaluation of `idx`, some blowing of generated machine code, but nonetheless it may be useful for some cases.

And if indices are constants it becomes even simpler

```
#define GET(kind, idx) CFG_ ## kind ## idx
```

This version has no memory / code overheads at all.

Comment: In C++, using macros is bad style. Try using inline functions instead.

Comment: @Trantor Yes, it is not a very elegant solution, but you can try to solve problem with templates or/and inline functions. I'm not sure that it will be easier than simple macro.